# Adding Excel data to an attribute table

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile with Mediterranean countries, and an attribute table such as the one below:
[image]

In an excel spreadsheet, I have population data for all of these countries, which I'd like to assign.

[image]

Is there a way I can export my excel data so that population of Italy is assigned directly to Italy in the attribute table for example?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a field in both the layer and the attribute table which contains the same values, e.g. the shortcuts for the countries. Then go to `layer - add layer - add virtual layer` and give the fields with the country-codes as unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have right to comments, so I will ask here and edit/delete accordingly.

Do you have a dictionary which links Country in excel (which are in short codes) to country_name in attribute table (which are full name)?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no I don't...